# Want to build multiple Dockerfile via Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible, dockerfile

I am trying to make Ansible-Playbook that builds multiple Dockerfile

```
│   ├── aa
│   │   ├── 11
│   │   │   └── ubuntu.18.04
│   │   │       └── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── 22
│   │   │   ├── ubuntu.16.04
│   │   │   │   └── Dockerfile
│   │   │   └── ubuntu.20.04
│   │   │       └── Dockerfile
│   │   ├── 33
│   │   │   └── ubuntu.20.04
│   │   │       └── Dockerfile
│   │   └── 44
│   │   │   └── ubuntu.18.04
│   │   │       └── Dockerfile
```

I attached my tree structure.

there are multiple directories such as aa bb and etc.

will there be more efficient way to get list and make build command?

I am now making every single playbook.
I think this is not a good way, but still this is better at least pressing every build command in hand.

```
  - name: Build aa 11 ubuntu 18.04 images 
    command: docker build -t "{{basic_directory}}/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04:{{version}}" .

  - name: Build aa 22 ubuntu 16.04 images 
    command: docker build -t "{{basic_directory}}/aa/22/ubuntu.16.04:{{version}}" .

  - name: Build aa 22 ubuntu 18.04 images 
    command: docker build -t "{{basic_directory}}/aa/22/ubuntu.18.04:{{version}}" .
```

---

adding codes

```
  - find:
      path: "{{basic_directory}}"
      recurse: true
      patterns: 'Dockerfile'
    register: result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the tree

```sh
shell> tree conf/
conf/
└── aa
    ├── 11
    │   └── ubuntu.18.04
    │       └── Dockerfile
    ├── 22
    │   ├── ubuntu.16.04
    │   │   └── Dockerfile
    │   └── ubuntu.20.04
    │       └── Dockerfile
    ├── 33
    │   └── ubuntu.20.04
    │       └── Dockerfile
    └── 44
        └── ubuntu.18.04
            └── Dockerfile
```

and the variables

```yaml
  basic_directory: conf
  version: '1.0'
```

---

Use the [*find*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/find_module.html#ansible-builtin-find-module-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) module to get the list of the paths

```yaml
    - find:
        path: "{{ basic_directory }}"
        recurse: true
        pattern: Dockerfile
      register: result
```

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path')|list:
  - conf/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04/Dockerfile
  - conf/aa/33/ubuntu.20.04/Dockerfile
  - conf/aa/44/ubuntu.18.04/Dockerfile
  - conf/aa/22/ubuntu.20.04/Dockerfile
  - conf/aa/22/ubuntu.16.04/Dockerfile
```

Iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          command: docker build -t {{ item|dirname }}:{{ version }} .
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/33/ubuntu.20.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/44/ubuntu.18.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/22/ubuntu.20.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/22/ubuntu.16.04:1.0 .'
```

---

Optionally, it is possible to find the directories only, e.g.

```yaml
    - find:
        path: "{{ basic_directory }}"
        recurse: true
        file_type: directory
        patterns: ubuntu*
      register: result
```

```yaml
  result.files|map(attribute='path')|list:
  - conf/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04
  - conf/aa/33/ubuntu.20.04
  - conf/aa/44/ubuntu.18.04
  - conf/aa/22/ubuntu.20.04
  - conf/aa/22/ubuntu.16.04
```

Iterate the list

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: >-
          command: docker build -t {{ item }}:{{ version }} .
      loop: "{{ result.files|map(attribute='path')|list }}"
```

gives the same result

```yaml
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/11/ubuntu.18.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/33/ubuntu.20.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/44/ubuntu.18.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/22/ubuntu.20.04:1.0 .'
  msg: 'command: docker build -t /tmp/aa/22/ubuntu.16.04:1.0 .'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
It seems quite complex than I thought. If you only gave me "find" module, it will be harder to solve this problem.
I should study more harder.
Have a nice day

Comment: Actually, In the file, there are not only Dockerfile. then should I try  adding 'patterns' option inside find module? I edited my post.